# Get limited amount of results from related table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Tables

```
post            category
-----           ----------
id              id
name            name
category_id
```

I get limited amount of posts for each category (if category have posts)

```
$categories = Category::get();
$categores_with_posts = array();

foreach($categories as $category)
{   
    $category_data = array(
        'posts' => Post::where('category_id', $category['id'])->take(10)->get()->toArray(),
        'category_id' => $category['id'],
        'name' => $category['name']
    );

    if(!empty($category_data['posts'])) {
        $categores_with_posts[] = $category_data;
    }
}
```

How can i do this in Laravel using one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **TESTED** code, but you should be able to create a relation between those two models:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

}

class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

    public function postsTop10()
    {
        return $this->posts()->take(10);
    }

}
```

And then use it to get your results:

```
$categories = Category::with('postsTop10')->get();

foreach($categories as $category)
{   
    foreach($category->postsTop10 as $post)
    {
        echo "$post->name";
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs in SQL as: `select * from post where post.category_id in (?, ?, ?, ?) limit 10` So i only get 10 posts from 1 category.

Comment: Just tested it here, of course, you'll need to use `$category->postsTop10`. Edited.

Comment: I used `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after `$categories = Category::with('postsTop10')->get();` and i got sql `select * from post where post.category_id in (?, ?, ?, ?) limit 10`. In foreach cycles i don't get additional data so it's still same 10 posts for 1 category. To make it work just need to get all categories by `$categories = Category::get();` Then `foreach($category->postsTop10 as $post)` will get 10 posts for each category. This is not done in a single query but i guess it's still the correct way. This was helpful :) Thanks